# Suspend module with module handle

Tags: c++, winapi, xbox360

I'm looking for a way to suspend a module with only the module handle. Alternatively is there a way I can grab the main thread handle with the module handle? I am still quite new to C++ so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't suspend modules. You can suspend threads although you should not do so. A module does not have a main thread. A process has a main thread.

Suspending a thread is not something that should be done in
a forceful way. Doing so leads to deadlocks. You should instead signal the thread to pause and then wait until it can do so. Let
the thread pause when it knows it is in a safe state to do so.

Sorry if this sounds unhelpful but you need to explain your real problem.